# Understanding Scala Implicits

Tags: scala, parsing, functional-programming, implicit, case-class

While reading *Functional Programming in Scala* by Chiusano and Bjarnason, I encountered the following code in chapter 9, Parser Combinators:

```
trait Parsers[ParseError, Parser[+_]] { self =>
  ...
  def or[A](s1: Parser[A], s2: Parser[A]): Parser[A]
  implicit def string(s: String): Parser[String]
  implicit def operators[A](p: Parser[A]) = ParserOps[A](p)
  implicit def asStringParser[A](a: A)(implicit f: A => Parser[String]):
    ParserOps[String] = ParserOps(f(a))

  case class ParserOps[A](p: Parser[A]) {
    def |[B>:A](p2: Parser[B]): Parser[B] = self.or(p,p2)
    def or[B>:A](p2: => Parser[B]): Parser[B] = self.or(p,p2)
  }
}
```

I understand that if there is a type incompatibility or missing parameters during compilation, the Scala compiler would look for a missing function that converts the non-matching type to the desired type or a variable in scope with the desired type that fits the missing parameter respectively.

If a string occurs in a place that requires a `Parser[String]`, the string function in the above trait should be invoked to convert the string to a `Parser[String]`.

However, I've difficulties understanding the `operators` and `asStringParser` functions. These are the questions that I have:

1. For the implicit operators function, why isn't there a return type?
2. Why is ParserOps defined as a `case class` and why can't the `|` or `or` function be defined in the Parsers trait itself?
3. What exactly is the `asStringParser` trying to accomplish? What is its purpose here?
4. Why is `self` needed? The book says, "Use self to explicitly disambiguate reference to the or method on the trait," but what does it mean?

I'm truly enjoying the book but the use of advanced language-specific constructs in this chapter is hindering my progress. It would be of great help if you can explain to me how this code works. I understand that the goal is to make the library "nicer" to use through operators like `|` and `or`, but don't understand how this is done.

Comment: 1) It's called *type inference* and is a fundamental feature of pretty much every programming language invented after 1973. 4) Because you want to call the `or` in `Parsers`, not the one in `ParserOps`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Every method has a return type. In this case, it's `ParserOps[A]`. You don't have to write it out explicitly, because in this case it can be inferred automatically.
2. Probably because of the automatically provided `ParserOps.apply`-factory method in the companion object. You need fewer `val`s in the constructor, and you don't need the `new` keyword to instantiate `ParserOps`. It is not used in pattern matching though, so, you could do the same thing with an ordinary (non-`case`) class, wouldn't matter.
3. It's the "pimp-my-library"-pattern. It attaches methods `|` and `or` to `Parser`, without forcing `Parser` to inherit from anything. In this way, you can later declare `Parser` to be something like `ParserState => Result[A]`, but you will still have methods `|` and `or` available (even though `Function1[ParserState, Result[A]]` does not have them).
4. You could put `|` and `or` directly in `Parsers`, but then you would have to use the syntax

   ```
   |(a, b)
   or(a, b)
   ```

   instead of the much nicer

   ```
   a | b
   a or b
   ```

There are no "real operators" in Scala, everything is a method. If you want to implement a method that behaves as if it were an infix operator, you do exactly what is done in the book.

Comment: Great answers - got myself stuck at this chapter of the book, but this explanation makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: ... but I still don't quite understand why `asStringParser` accepts an arbitrary type `A` plus an implicit converting it into a string parser.

Comment: @Grisha The `A => Parser[String]` part is there so that, for example, the implicit method can take an `A = String` as argument, then turn it into a `Parser[String]` using `string`, and then immediately turn it into `ParserOps`, so that you effectively get parser-combinator operations on `String`s. It's called "chaining implicit conversions". Take a look at [this FAQ](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/chaining-implicits.html), specifically at the shape of the `bToC` conversion in the second code block. It's the same with `B1 = A`, `B = Parser[String]`, `C = ParserOps[String]`.

Comment: Thanks! Are they trying to stay as flexible as possible with `A` anticipating that it could be smth else other `String`, as long as there is an implicit `A => Parser[String]` conversion? I'm failing to image a use case for that.

Comment: @Grisha How about combination of `String`s `or` compiled `Regex` patterns `or` more complex compositions of general `Parser[X]`s, for example?

Comment: a little addendum: Scala seems to avoid chaining more than one implicit conversions except if the conversion itself requires an implicit parameter. So a simple chain `String->string()->Parser[String]->operators()->ParserOps[String]` wouldn't work, hence `asStringParser()`